# Duplicate screen lag on Android

Tags: screen, hardware, lagging

Each time I turn on my LG G3 after some pause (30 sec + ) when the display is turned off I get this weird lag. Like the screen is duplicated on half the screen. Then After 2 seconds it get normal.

Also, when I call someone and the screen turns black while i hold it to my ear, if it takes more than 20-30 seconds, when I pull it from my ear to close the call it happens again(lasting 2-4 seconds). It looks something like this:

[image]

I tried turning off animations and it seems to work a bit better but still have this problem. Not sure if it's software problem or my device is faulted.

Comment: did you try a factory reflash if this was bothering you that much?

Comment: Yes. it didn't work. Well it bothers me because I literally can't close a phone call sometimes for 5-8 seconds if the other person doesn't hang up. Also, I think I want to sell it.

Comment: It is then probably a screen defect. It could have been caused due to physical shock. I've seen similar problems on my mom's phone when it fell, although it had Gorilla Glass 2.You could try to get it repaired or sell it. Should I make this an answer?

Comment: The phone literally looks perfect. No scratch, no nothing. Although it might be the case.

Comment: It doesn't need to look broken to be broken. Also, do you use a case? And sometimes electrical discharges near the charger port can cause this issue.

Comment: @TamoghnaChowdhury I think indeed it is a faulty device and the problem is on the motherboard level from what I could find online. If you want to convert your comments into an answer I can close the topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a factory image flash hasn't helped you, and with the information provided in the comments, the problem is at the hardware level. It may be in the screen or the input processing hardware on the motherboard. You could try getting the device repaired. Note that the device does not need to look broken to be broken.